# Elastic beanstalk rails application with git source and deploy hooks

Tags: deployment, amazon-web-services, rails

I want to setup Elastic Beanstalk for my existing rails application.

I was successful in doing the sample foo app.

These are the questions I have

I need the deployment to happen from my git repository and not from my local path where I am deploying. How do I do that for the sample foo app.

The git aws.push command seems to deploy on the new ec2 instance. However, it did not push the changes to my git repository. Should I do a git push separately before doing a git aws.push ? Notice that my branch is ahead by 1 commit when I do a git status.  Does aws maintain a separate git repository ? How can I get it to use my git repository instead ?

```
[mymac:~/Projects/new/foo(master)]$ git aws.push
Counting objects: 4949, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1115/1115), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4949/4949), 14.11 MiB | 1.90 MiB/s, done.
Total 4949 (delta 3800), reused 4944 (delta 3798)
remote: 
To https://AKIAJZT3WFY2WLO6CHQQ:20121127T030627Zf56675b2f4c9c731ca6f51b11d36a438e8bcee25c5171061ce5ac681495318c9@git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/617069/commitid/39396162666436346439656465313537613561343561626465643931393366623762386265303138/environment/6170692d656e76
 * [new branch]      HEAD -> master


[mymac:~/Projects/new/foo(master)]$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Below is the result of just a git push.

```
[mymac:~/Projects/new/foo(master)]$ git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 340 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:xxxx/foo.git
   885cc33..99abfd6  master -> master
```

Separately, I need to have a before_symlink deploy hook. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't clear from your question if you have already tried the `git aws.push` option. You could refer [a blog post](http://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AK2MFX0QHRIO/Deploying-Ruby-Applications-to-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk-with-Git) on AWSBlog for deploying Rack based applications to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. To summarize the same, you can do it in the following easy steps:

1. `eb init`
2. `eb start`
3. `git aws.push`

This, of course, requires you to download AWS Elastic Beanstalk command line tools.

AFAIK, AWS Elastic Beanstalk does not have an integration with Git deploy hooks yet, but it's pretty simple if you are already using a CI Server like Jenkins. Github can very well integrate with most CI servers. You could achieve a `git push` triggering `git aws.push` from your CI server by adding a new Jenkins job with custom Shell commands. You may also want to execute a test harness before pushing a fresh build out there. Jenkins or Travis CI will do the job for you!

Regarding the execution of `before_symlink` type tasks, the way AWS Elastic Beanstalk works is different from a traditional Capistrano deployment. It bundles all your code into an executable archive and simply copies it over to load-balanced nodes. For executing `before_symlink` like tasks, you might want to write some custom configuration files and place them under `.ebextensions` in the root path of your Git repository. The way I did it is by adding a `.ebextensions/symlink.config` file. Here's a sample code for symlinking your `database.yml` file on the server.

```
container_commands:
  symlink-db:
    command: ln -sf /var/app/shared/database.yml $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK/config/database.yml
```

Please note that I am running a custom AMI with a `/var/app/shared/` directory which, otherwise, is not present when you launch a vanilla Ruby container. Further, `$EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK` environment variable holds the current deployment directory name (typically `/var/app/ondeck`) which is moved to `/var/app/current` once the deployment is through and before restarting the Rails (Passenger) server, thus making it available for serving requests. Read more on [Customizing AWS Elastic Beanstalk containers](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question regarding git aws.push. Could you please take a look at that and tell me

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way, but I always did a `git push` followed by a `git aws.push`. Since my environment was set up with Jenkins CI, `git push` happened on my development machine whereas `git aws.push` happened from the CI server.

Comment: Regarding the ebextensions.. is there a way I can debug why my command is not being executed. I tried symbolic link for database.yml that you have given... for some reason the symbolic link was not created. Any debug guidelines would be useful. I tried to run the command after the deployment by replacing $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK to /var/app/current and the command as such worked.

Comment: I'm not aware of any debugging technique at the moment. I even tried to look for some, but could not find standard guidelines to do so. About the symbolic link, just confirming, do you have a `/var/app/shared` directory on the instance? Manual symlinking will always work. Did you check the value of `EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK` environment variable? Can you paste the output of `echo $EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK`?

Comment: Hey, things are fine now. I had another clarification. I want to start up a process only after the EB_CONFIG_APP_ONDECK folder has been moved to current folder. So, it is basically a post-deployment process. How would I do that ? Having ebextensions does everything before EB_CONFIG_APP_DECK has been transferred to current

Comment: Not sure about this one, but I think it can be done using services. http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html#customize-containers-format-services

Answer (score 0):

I was able to integrate Travis CI test builds with Amazon Beanstalk deployments. In order to do this i had to automate eb tools, because the current version 2.5.1 only runs in an interactive way, so I edited EB tools code on some python files and then created a .travis.yml file with the appropriate instructions to deploy the app to AWS Beanstalk.

Here is a link to my blog that gives a complete description of the process:

http://www.sysadminops.com/amazon-beanstalk-and-travis-ci-integration/

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. I implore you to not let touting your blog be your only contribution to this site, however valuable a solution it may be.

Comment: Just a heads up, your link ends up taking you to a spammy site. A WARNING to anyone who's about to click it :)